# MySQL connection error: resource(2) of type (mysql link)

Tags: php, mysql-connect

I have this problem:

```
 <?php
   $link = mysql_connect('123.123.123.123', 'user', 'pass');
   if (!$link) {
      die('con_error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
   mysql_select_db('db', $link) or die(mysql_error());

   echo 'connect!'."\n\n";

   var_dump($link);
   //var_dump($link->mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1'));
   mysql_close($link);
   exit();
   ?>
```

There are no errors and print "connect!". But then, i can't select anything - i get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function mysql_query() on a non-object i

`var_dump($link)` prints `resource(2) of type (mysql link)` and i cant find what does it means!

All connection attributes are correct. I can connect to DB from command line...
What should i do?

Comment: Well, what should we say? You don't show the code doing the actual query...

Comment: And when will people finally understand what "deprecated" means as it is written in the documentation of that old `mysql` php extension you use.

Comment: `$link` is **not** an object, you **cannot** call methods through it!

Comment: *Today I code a little bit OOP but some parts not.* - why the heck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$link` is **not** an object, you **cannot** call methods through it!

What you want is

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1', $link);
```

but please note that `mysql_*` functions are **deprecated**, use [**`PDO`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.